# In Xcode 6.2 how do you add a Run Script build phase that runs a Swift script?

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to run a Swift script as part of my Xcode project build but I'm getting many errors when I add it. (Screenshot showing some of the errors is attached.) Am I missing something?

My run script build phase looks like this:

```
(Shell: /bin/sh)
swift path/to/my/script
```

[image: errors]

Answer (score 1):

You have to include full path to swift which would be for current release
  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift path/to/your/script`

Or for any beta version of Xcode it would be

```
${PATH_TO_XCODE_BETA_DOT_APP}/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift path/to/your/script
```

Or you my just write you script directly in run script build phase like so :

[image]